# jQuery "Fuel" Gauge for answering questions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been tasked with creating a "fuel" kind of gauge which will be used as a way of answering questions.

For an example of what I mean have a look at this: http://swisspeaks.com/dev/slider.html

It needs to have that functionality but look like this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7017086/gauge.jpg

I've seen [this](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/widget/AnalogGauge) already but it doesn't do what I want. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Not going to write this for you, but I would consider the following outline: mouse movements + sin and cos, and for extra points, add snap-to-grid availability!

Comment: What kind of help do you want? Are you looking for something out of the box? Are you trying to implement it, but you are stuck with a question? Are you trying to use dojo but want to change its look? Please improve the question, right now it's too broad and sounds like, please implement it for me.

Comment: I was looking to see if something already existed that did this?

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm not that familiar with jquery and I only know a bit of javascript in general, But with a bit of thinkering [that](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/widget/AnalogGauge) (by you linked as this) will do what you want...

From what I've learned: If something is close enough but just needs that last push, edit it!